# Problema con programa en C, scanf no responde

Tags: c, revisión-de-código

tengo el siguiente código en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct alumnos{
char nombre[10];
char dni[20];
int edad;
};

int main(){
struct alumnos myAlumnos[2];
char opcion[20];
char salir[20] = "salir";
int i,status;

for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
    printf("Ingresa el nombre del alumno  numero %i: ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",&myAlumnos[i].nombre[10]);

    printf("Ingresa el dni del alumno numero %i: ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",&myAlumnos[i].dni[20]);

    printf("Ingresa la edad del alumno numero %i: ",i+1);
    scanf("%i",&myAlumnos[i].edad);
}

do{
    while(getchar() != "\n");
    status = 1;
    printf("Ingrese un dni: ");
    gets(opcion);
    if(strcmp(opcion,salir)!=0){
        i=0;
        while(i<=2 && status!=0){
            if(strcmp(myAlumnos[i].dni,opcion)==0){
                printf("Nombre del alumno: %s\nEdad: %i",myAlumnos[i].nombre,myAlumnos[i].edad);
                status=0;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}while(strcmp(opcion,salir)!=0);
}
```

Y al llegar al `scanf("%i",&myAlumnos[i].edad);` de la tercera iteración del `for` (ósea cuando `i == 2`) presiono *enter* para continuar luego de ingresar el dato y el programa no hace nada, puedo seguir escribiendo en la pantalla pero es como si la tecla enter no respondiera... ¿Alguna idea?

utilizo el IDE CodeLite en OSX El Capitan

Comment: Cuando `i` es `2` estás escribiendo fuera del arreglo de `myAlumnos`; esto podría provocar tu fallo.

Comment: Creo que gran parte de tu problema se encuentra en esta linea`while(getchar() != "\n");` No hay llaves que indiquen que el código siguiente se va a ejecutar y el `;` se va a "ejecutar" siempre, el error no está en la parte que mencionas... Lo he probado y se ejecuta perfectamente.

Comment: @NaCl si precisamente el problema estaba en el while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modo de respuesta, gran parte de tu problema se encuentra en esta linea:

```
while(getchar() != "\n");
```

Precisamente en esta parte `;` al no haber ningún statement o sentencia que ejecutar, el simplemente se queda en esa sentencia `while`.

Pero y si envío un `\n` desde el teclado, ¿Por qué no lo reconoce? No tengo muy clara esta respuesta, pero debe ser porque no es el ultimo caracter en enviarse.

**Solución:**

Arregla ese bloque por el siguiente:

```
while(getchar() != "\n") 
{
    status = 1;
    printf("Ingrese un dni: ");
    gets(opcion);
    printf("%i", strcmp(opcion, salir));
    if(strcmp(opcion, salir) != 0) 
    {
        i = 0;
        while (i <= 2 && status != 0) 
        {
            if(strcmp(myAlumnos[i].dni, opcion) == 0) 
            {
                printf("Nombre del alumno: %s\nEdad: %i",myAlumnos[i].nombre,myAlumnos[i].edad);
                status = 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

*¡Oh wow, me he equivocado, pero todos somos humanos!*

#### Edit 2:

Estas haciendo una comparación de `string` a dos datos de tipo int... Nunca van a ser iguales :(

```
strcmp(myAlumnos[i].dni,opcion) == 0
```

El tipo `char` si es un tipo de base integral, pero ejemplo: `' ' es igual a 32` pero, `myAlumnos[i].dni = 321` y `opcion = "321"` ¿Cuál es el valor del resultado de `strcmp`? (A mi me dió -66).

Y a modo de adición, lo que dice [dminones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16624/4499) en su respuesta, tiene razón, en otros lenguajes de programación no hubieras podido acceder al elemento `[2]` de tu `Array` si el tamaño de este es precisamente 2.

---

#### Edit:

No sé si entiendes muy bien el uso de `strcmp(str, str)` pero voy a hacer una referencia breve:

```
string A = "Hola";
string B = "Hola";
int Comparacion = strcmp(A, B); // Comparacion == 0
```

`strcmp()` devuelve cero si ambos strings son iguales, cualquier otro número si no lo son.

Por lo que no creo que debas comparar dentro del `if` : `(strcmp(opcion,salir)!=0)`. más bien creo que debes comparar si existe un registro con ese dni, si no existe, la condición establecida en el ciclo `do .. while` se encargará automaticamente de saber si lo que se introdujo en el teclado fué `"salir"`.

Referencia: [strcmp (en ingles)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: Era el while que no me dejaba ejecutar el programa normalmente pero el problema es que en el curso que estoy siguiendo usan ese método para "limpiar el buffer del teclado" o algo por el estilo...

Comment: Entonces, gran parte de tu problema está resuelto! Procede a escribir una respuesta si ya lo solucionaste!

Answer (score 0):

deberías usar < ya que tu array tiene 2 valores no 3

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
```

O bien poner 3 en la definición del array

```
struct alumnos myAlumnos[3];
```